# Is the Derivation Algebra functorial

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory

Suppose $A$ is a commutative, associative $k$-algebra with unit and 
$Der(A)\subset End_k(A,A)$ is the algebra of *derivations* on $A$, that is
the subalgebra of endomorphisms, such that

$D(ab)=D(a)b+aD(b)$ for all $a,b\in A$ and $D\in Der(A)$.

Is this functorial on the category of commutative, associative $k$-algebras? 
If yes, how are the appropriate morphisms $Der(f):Der(A)\to Der(B)$ obtained 
from $f:A\to B$ and if not .. why? What goes wrong?

Comment: This is an infinitesimal version of an automorphism group, which you don't expect to be functorial except with respect to automorphisms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Der}{Der}$The right notion here isn't $\Der(A)$, it's $\Der_k(A,M)$. It is functorial on the category $\mathcal{C}$:

- whose objects are pairs $(A,M)$ where $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $M$ is an $A$-module;
- whose morphisms $(A,M) \to (B, N)$ are pairs $(f, \phi)$ where:

  - $f : A \to B$ is a morphism of algebras;
  - $\phi : f^* N \to M$ is a map of $A$-modules (where $f^* N$ has the structure induced by $f$).

The composition of $(f, \phi) : (A, M) \to (B, N)$ and $(g, \psi) : (B,N) \to (C,P)$ is given by $gf$ and the map $(gf)^* P = f^* (g^* P) \xrightarrow{f^* \psi} f^* N \xrightarrow{\phi} M$.

$\Der_k$ is given by:
$$\Der{}_k(A,M) = \{ D : A \to M \mid D(ab) = D(a) b + a D(b) \}$$

Then this is a contravariant functor on $\mathcal{C}$: if $(f,\phi) : (A,M) \to (B,N)$, the induced map $\Der(f,\phi) : \Der(B,N) \to \Der(A,M)$ is given by
$$\Der(f,\phi)(D)(a) = \phi(D(f(a)))$$

Comment: What do you mean with the right notation? $Der_k(A)$ is well defined and the center of the question.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus: I mean that $\Der(A)$ is not functorial, and if you want something functorial, then you should consider $\Der(A,M)$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: What goes wrong is exactly the fact that you need a map $A \to B$ but also a map in the "other direction" $f^* N \to M$. If you learn about sheaves and schemes later you'll see that this comes up too.

Comment: Suppose I already knew about sheaves. Then what else to say? -- And why 'later' ? Is posting a question at math.stackexchange now considered to be only for undergraduates?

Comment: Well in this case look at the definition of a morphism of ringed spaces / schemes. You'll see that it's a continuous map $f : X \to Y$ together with a morphism of sheaves $f^* O_Y \to O_X$: a map in the "right direction" and a map in the other one.

Comment: yes, but I don't see how this implys, that $Der_k(A)$ can't be functorial

Comment: No that's not what I meant, it's just another situation where this kind of things comes up.

Comment: ah ok. I think I was just hoping to get somehow around this second map, but that was wishful thinking.